# Replacing values lower than threshold using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have

```
int[] source = new[]{ 1, 3, 8, 9, 4 };
```

What linq query should I write in order to replace all values in the source, below some threshold, with zeros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int threshold = 2;
int[] dest = source.Select(i => i < threshold ? 0 : i).ToArray();
```

If you don't want to create a new array but use the old:

```
for(int index=0; index < source.Length; index++)
{
    if(source[index] < threshold)
       source[index] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really after replacement *within* (rather than *of*) the array, don't use LINQ, just

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    if (source[i] < threshold)
        source[i] = 0;
```